# Cómo convertir un arreglo Object a cualquier tipo de Arreglo en Java

Tags: java, array, conversión-de-tipos

Me refiero a que si tengo un arreglo de enteros int enteros[] = {1,2,3,4,5}
y un arreglo Object que guarde solo enteror Object objetos[] = {5,4,3,2,1}

¿Como puedo igualar el arreglo object al de enteros?

**ES UN EJEMPLO, me refiero a que si el arreglo de Object contiene cadenas y lo guarde en un arreglo String[] este me lo permita, si tiene solo caracteres que lo pueda guadar en un char[] y asi con esa logica.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No se puede hacer directamente.

Imagina que puedas hacer:

```
Object objetos[] = new Object[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int numeros[] = (int[]) objetos;
```

Vale, no parece que se haya hecho algo ilegal. Pero, y si a continuación:

```
objetos[0] = "Pepito";
int miNumero = numeros[0];
```

¿qué pasa?

Las dos líneas de justo arriba compilan, pero causan un error. A Java no le gusta esto, y quiere que si haces una "conversión" a una subclase hagas un cast explícito. Por eso, no se puede hacer la conversión directa.

Solución: Crea un nuevo array del tipo objetivo, y recorre el array original asignando los valores.

Comment: Y, además, int es un tipo primitivo, no es un objeto, con lo que los problemas aumentarían al hacer algo así

Comment: No se que quieras hacer exactamente, pero como tu dices si el arreglo de Object[] tiene puros String, que te lo permita guardar en un arreglo de String[]. Para eso tienes que iterar sobre todo el arreglo para asegurarte que todos los elementos son String,  de esta manera: **objetos[0] instanceof String** , sino de otra forma como dice @SJuan76 te marcará un Exception ( java.lang.ClassCastException) en: int numeros[] = (int[]) objetos;

Comment: Pues supuse que no se podría por esas razones, esque estaba trabajando con Grafos y queria evitarme optar por el camino facil de los arraylist, lo que yo si puedo conseguir es agrandar un arreglo del mismo tipo, entonces todos mis arreglos los hice tipo Object y el metodo que tengo de agrandar un arreglo retorna el mismo arreglo object con un elemento al final, y asi poder agrandar y eliminar posiciones de todos mis arreglos Objects que guardan un mismo valor cada uno (int, char, u Objetos ) Gracias por la Respuesta.